# php's Gauss-Jordan Elimination code

Tags: php, linear-algebra, algebra

I'd like to write a code to make gaussian elimination, i got this:

```
function gauss($A, $x) {

    for ($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++) {
        $A[$i][] = $x[$i];
    }
    $n = count($A);

    for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $maxEl = abs($A[$i][$i]);
        $maxRow = $i;
        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) {
            if (abs($A[$k][$i]) > $maxEl) {
                $maxEl = abs($A[$k][$i]);
                $maxRow = $k;
            }
        }


        for ($k=$i; $k < $n+1; $k++) {
            $tmp = $A[$maxRow][$k];
            $A[$maxRow][$k] = $A[$i][$k];
            $A[$i][$k] = $tmp;
        }

        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) {
            $c = -$A[$k][$i]/$A[$i][$i];
            for ($j=$i; $j < $n+1; $j++) {
                if ($i==$j) {
                    $A[$k][$j] = 0;
                } else {
                    $A[$k][$j] += $c * $A[$i][$j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $x = array_fill(0, $n, 0);
    for ($i=$n-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $x[$i] = $A[$i][$n]/$A[$i][$i];
        for ($k=$i-1; $k > -1; $k--) {
            $A[$k][$n] -= $A[$k][$i] * $x[$i];
        }
    }
if (!in_array(false, $x, true)){
 if($x[0] >= 0 && $x[1] >= 0 && $x[2] >= 0){
return $x;
}
}

}
```

Everything is OK but when i put values like this:

```
$A = array(array(1,1,0),array(3,5,4),array(1,0,0));
$x = array(2,30,0);



| 1 1 0 |  2 | 
| 1 0 0 |  0 |
| 3 5 4 | 30 |
```

The result should be: (0,2,5), but my function returns null.

I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: I have not checked your Gaussian elimination routine in detail but I noticed already that you only allow the function to return the `$x` vector if all values are `>=0`. Is not that a condition that goes to far? What about legitimate solutions involving negative `$x` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried my assumption mentioned in my earlier comment and it turned out to be true: removing the conditions before returning you result vector will solve your problem. Try it out in this [little phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n5m9-vgsi).

Here the corrected code again:

```
function gauss($A, $x) {

    for ($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++) {
        $A[$i][] = $x[$i];
    }
    $n = count($A);

    for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $maxEl = abs($A[$i][$i]);
        $maxRow = $i;
        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) {
            if (abs($A[$k][$i]) > $maxEl) {
                $maxEl = abs($A[$k][$i]);
                $maxRow = $k;
            }
        }


        for ($k=$i; $k < $n+1; $k++) {
            $tmp = $A[$maxRow][$k];
            $A[$maxRow][$k] = $A[$i][$k];
            $A[$i][$k] = $tmp;
        }

        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) {
            $c = -$A[$k][$i]/$A[$i][$i];
            for ($j=$i; $j < $n+1; $j++) {
                if ($i==$j) {
                    $A[$k][$j] = 0;
                } else {
                    $A[$k][$j] += $c * $A[$i][$j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $x = array_fill(0, $n, 0);
    for ($i=$n-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $x[$i] = $A[$i][$n]/$A[$i][$i];
        for ($k=$i-1; $k > -1; $k--) {
            $A[$k][$n] -= $A[$k][$i] * $x[$i];
        }
    }
    // be bold and return the $x vector in any case:
    return $x;
}
$A = array(array(1,1,0),array(3,5,4),array(1,0,0));
$rhs = array(2,30,0);
print_r($A);
print_r($rhs);
$x=gauss($A,$rhs);
echo "solution vector:\n";
print_r($x);
```

This give the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 0
)
solution vector:
Array
(
    [0] => -5.92118946467E-16
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
)
```

Comment: I know that, but there is something wrong with this algorithm. Because correct output array should be: (0,2,5).

Comment: Well, that is as close to `0` as you will ever get! In a numeric sense `-5.92118946467E-16` **is** zero. It is "very small" compared to `2 `and `5`. If you want to make it look better, you could try to `round()` the results.